# Can `auto_id` and `id_for_label` ever have different values?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-1.10

Both `{{ form.myfield.auto_id }}` and `{{ form.myfield.id_for_label }}` have the same value. Usually it's "id_myfield".

It is usually used to construct forms, so technically they should always be the same.

```
<label for="{{ form.myfield.id_for_label }}">...</label>
<input id="{{ form.myfield.auto_id }}" />
```

But I wonder why `id_for_label` even exists, because it just adds unnecessary overhead to something that can be done with only `auto_id`. Are there cases where the values are different?

Answer (score -1):

Django documentation states following

> [BoundField.id_for_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.id_for_label)
>
> By default, this will be the field’s name prefixed by id_
>   (“id_my_field” for the example above). You may modify the ID by
>   setting attrs on the field’s widget. For example, declaring a field
>   like this:
>
> `my_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':
>   'myFIELD'})`)